# Prove that a logarithm is irrational

Tags: logarithms

I’m stuck with the following problem:

Prove that $\log_{2} 3 \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}  $ .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it really correct to denote $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ as $\mathbb R- \mathbb Q$?

Comment: Prove??  Heck, I've *known* they were irrational ever since Mr Jesse first talked about them!

Comment: @mathh Yes. Those are two different notations for the same thing. I prefer $\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$, because it is clearer to me, but other people prefer $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 15):

Suppose that $\log_23$ is rational, i.e.
$$\log_23=\frac{n}{m}$$
where $m,n$ are positive integers.

Then, we have
$$\log_23=\log_22^{\frac{n}{m}}\Rightarrow 3=2^{\frac nm}\Rightarrow 3^m=2^n.$$
Here, the LHS is odd and the RHS is even, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that
$$\log_2(3)=\frac{p}{q},$$
you get:
$$ 3 = 2^{p/q}$$
or:
$$ 3^q = 2^p, $$
contradiction.